# How do I group by a value which is a substring in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example: column name is `ID`.

The text of each column is like `... user=##### ...` (where `...` is some other random text, and `#####` is some 5-digit number)

And I want to count the number of times each `#####` appears (count descending)

Seems like this shouldn't be so hard, I'm probably missing something?

Comment: Is the width of the text always fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Also I know "user" should have been made its own column, unfortunately that's not in my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One viable option might be to take a substring of the `ID` column which is five characters long and which begins after the occurrence of `user=`:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('user=', ID) + 5, 5),
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('user=', ID) + 5, 5);
```

Comment: Ah, I was misunderstanding CHARINDEX. Thanks! Worked great!